# apply coefficient and intercept of previous day to on next day data

Tags: python-3.x

I have below df which are contains coefficient and intercept daywise:

```
Day            coefficient        intercept
01-01-2019       0.21               1.21
01-02-2019       0.20               1.22
01-03-2019       0.19               1.23
01-04-2019       0.18               1.24
01-05-2019       0.22               1.25
01-06-2019       0.23               1.26
01-07-2019       0.24               1.27
01-08-2019       0.25               1.28
01-09-2019       0.26               1.29
```

I would like to multiply coefficient and add intercept to 'col1' data in below time series data daywise.

```
date                 col1      col2        New Col(*coeff+intercept)
01-01-2019 00:00      0.9       0.11
01-01-2019 00:10      0.8       0.12
01-01-2019 00:20      0.7       0.13
01-01-2019 00:30      0.6       0.14
01-01-2019 00:40      0.5       0.15
01-01-2019 00:50      0.4       0.16
01-02-2019 00:00      0.1       0.17         1.231
01-02-2019 00:10      0.2       0.18         1.252
01-02-2019 00:20      0.3       0.19         1.273 
01-02-2019 00:30      0.4       0.90         1.294
01-02-2019 00:40      0.5       0.90         1.315
01-02-2019 00:50      0.6       0.90         1.336
01-03-2019 00:00      0.7       0.90         1.36
01-03-2019 00:10      0.8       0.90         1.38
01-03-2019 00:20      0.9       0.90         1.4
01-03-2019 00:30      0.1       0.90         1.24
```

But I wants to apply coefficient and intercept of previous day to on next day data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are the dataframes

```
df_COEF_IC = ['date','Coefficient','Intercept']
df = ['date','col1','col2']
```

1st you have to shift data of date one day ahead

```
df_COEF_IC['Shiffted Date'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df_stat['day']) + pd.DateOffset(1)
df_COEF_IC = ['date','coefficient','intercept','Shiffted Date']
```

In loop,now u can multiply coefficient and add the intercept

```
for i in range(len(df_COEF_IC)):
    COEF = df_COEF_IC.loc[i,'coefficient'] 
    IC = df_COEF_IC.loc[i,'intercept']
    COEF_Day = df_COEF_IC.loc[i,'Shifted_date']
    for j in range(len(df)):
        current_day = df.loc[j,'date']
        if COEF_Day == current_day:
            df.loc[j,'result'] = COEF*df.loc[j,'col1']+IC
```

Answer (score 0):

***Just assign both of your dataframes as original and new and try to run the below code.***

**original**: Dataframe with coefficient and intercept values

**new**: Dataframe with Datetime value

```
# Iterating over new dataframe
for i, element in enumerate(new["date"]):

    # Finding corresponding date in original
    result = original[original.eq(element.date()).any(1)]

    # coefficient and intercept value from original table
    # for particular datetime value from new table
    c, i_ = result["coefficient"], result["intercept"]
    col1v = new.iloc[i:i+1]["col1"]

    # Adding result of multiplication into another column
    new["result"].iloc[i:i+1] = np.add(np.multiply(col1v, c), i_)
```

Check this [notebook](https://gist.github.com/shravankumar9892/a3fe19dc2a2913dcd41faef68ca0c203) for the demo.

Comment: Thanks for your support, in above code i didn't get desired output its showing NaN values. In your code coefficient & intercept of 26th day are 0.544811 ,1.555167 & after apply coefficient & intercept of 26th data to 27th data to 'col1' value of 0.233043 it should be come 1.682108 but in your output its showing 1.186708

Comment: You were getting NaN values because you didn't put the result into `new["result"].iloc[i:i+1] = np.add(np.multiply(col1v, c), i_)` . And since we are using random.randn it would show random values for you and me both. So try rerunning the above snippet once more and tell me if it's giving the correct answer.

Comment: I have also updated the [notebook](https://gist.github.com/shravankumar9892/a3fe19dc2a2913dcd41faef68ca0c203), check it out.

Comment: I tried your code with your data but its giving 1st 2 value output afterthat its showing NaN values

Comment: Did you download and try to run the [notebook](https://gist.github.com/shravankumar9892/a3fe19dc2a2913dcd41faef68ca0c203)?